# A Blank Page Before Title Page

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass[3pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{nicefrac}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\def\lVert{\mid\!\mid}
\def\rVert{\mid\!\mid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\regret}{regret}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\textsc{\LARGE
University College Dublin
} \\[1cm]
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{UCDlogo.png} \\[1cm]
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries xyz \\[0.15cm]}
\HRule \\[0.5cm]
ABC\\
CDE\\
SCH\\
UVW\\
NYT\\
Date Of Assessment: xyz\\
Supervisor: Prof. xyt\\
\end{titlepage}
\end{center}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Specification of research area}
\end{document}
```

could you please help me to remove the blank page before the title page?

Comment: Welcoeme to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic:n (a) `3pt` is not a valid option for the `report` document class and is therefore simply ignored. (b) No need define `\lVert` and `\rVert`, especially not in the way you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order you open the `center` and the `titlepage` environments seems to work. I guess the `center` environment tries to make the `titlepage` centered, instead of centering only the contents of the titlepage.

```
\documentclass[3pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{nicefrac}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\def\lVert{\mid\!\mid}
\def\rVert{\mid\!\mid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\regret}{regret}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\textsc{\LARGE
University College Dublin
} \\[1cm]
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{UCDlogo.png} \\[1cm]
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries xyz \\[0.15cm]}
\HRule \\[0.5cm]
ABC\\
CDE\\
SCH\\
UVW\\
NYT\\
Date Of Assessment: xyz\\
Supervisor: Prof. xyt\\
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Specification of research area}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem and the only thing that solved it for me was adding a total to the geometry as described in the documentation (http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf, page 2)

```
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},
top=1.2in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in, includefoot]{geometry}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!